# Jquery post request returns empty data

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have been working on cinema project using java servlets and jquery, and been doing quite well till now...
Yesterday, everything was working fine but today I just can't run one important post request to my servlet, I can trigger it but can't read value of returned data...
Here is post request

```
getProjection : function(ID) {
            params = {
                    'action': 'getProjection',
                    'id': ID
            };
            $.post('ProjectionsServlet', params, function(data) {

                console.log(data); //this is empty

            });

        }
```

Here is my servlet that handles requests

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        try {
            switch(action) {
                case "add": {
                    break;
                }
                case "getProjection": {
                    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
                    Projection projection = ProjectionDAO.get(id);
                    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("projection", projection);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    String jsonDataProjection = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);

                    //I printed jsonDataProjection here and it returns the object

                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().write(jsonDataProjection);
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have identical calls for entity movie which works perfectly, actually everything in project works perfectly except only this one call. I'm sure it's some obvious mistake but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: I'm not a big java person, but do you need to flush the response so that it finishes writing to the output? Also, not sure that catch will print anywhere.

Comment: I don't think that's problem, I literally copied getMovie method which is the same as getProjection and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving it away to new servlet in get method, still didn't figure out why it wasn't working